# Syntax for a function with closure and arguments in a function on Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures, alamofire

I looked around stackoverflow and tried to find what I need, but couldn't find it, if its duplicate, please point me in the right direction.

The question is, the syntax when trying to call a function that has a argument and a closure to it is confusing me. All the examples found seem to have a completion handler only, and no arguments to it.

I'm using Alamofire and want to make a wrapper class that handles some stuff that would be redundant to implement it all over the program.

What I have is

```
class ApiInterface{

    func getFromAPI( targetURL: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, targetURL, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
            completionHandler(response.result.value as? NSDictionary, response.result.error as? NSError)
        }
    }    
}
```

My idea was

```
ApiInterface().getFromAPI{ targetURL, (response, error) in 


}
```

but this causes and error and the XCode error messages don't help much.

I don't think its not possible to do this, so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ApiInterface().getFromAPI(targetURL, completionHandler: { (response, error) in
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the closure is getFromAPI's final argument, you could also use trailing closure syntax:

```
ApiInterface().getFromAPI(targetURL) { (response, error) -> () in
    // do stuff
}
```

It is functionally equivalent to the previous answer but some people find it more readable.